# Code for retrieving followers from Twitter API results in all followers having the same ID

Tags: python, twitter

I would like to scrape the Twitter API to retrieve the follower ids for specific users, so that I can map their connections.

When I run the code below, the `followerIds` for each individual user are the same, which can't be right:

```
    try:
        import json
    except ImportError:
        import simplejson as json
        import urllib2
        import urllib
        import codecs
        import time
        import datetime
        import os
        import random
        import time
        import tweepy
    from tweepy.parsers import RawParser
        import sys

    fhLog = codecs.open("LOG.txt",'a','UTF-8')
    def logPrint(s):
    fhLog.write("%s\n"%s)
    print s

    #List of screennames of users whose followers we want to get
    users =["_AReichert",
    "_CindyWallace_",
    "_MahmoudAbdelal",
    "1939Ford9N",
    "1FAMILY2MAN",
    "8Amber8",
    "AboutTeaching",
    "AcamorAcademy",
    "acraftymom",
    "ActivNews",
    "ActuVideosPub",
    "ad_jonez",
    "adamsteaching",
    "ADHD_HELP",
    "AIHEHistory",
    "ajpodchaski",
    "ak2mn",
    "AkaMsCrowley",
    "AlanAwstyn",
    "albertateachers"]


     # == OAuth Authentication ==


    # The consumer keys can be found on your application's Details
    # page located at https://dev.twitter.com/apps (under "OAuth settings")
     consumer_key=""
     consumer_secret=""

    # After the step above, you will be redirected to your app's page.
    # Create an access token under the the "Your access token" section
    access_token=""
    access_token_secret=""


    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    rawParser = RawParser()
    api = tweepy.API(auth_handler=auth, parser=rawParser)


    #Will store ids of followers for each user in the user_output directory
    os.system("mkdir -p user_output") #Create directory if it does not exist

    userCnt=0
    fhOverall=None
    for user in users:
         userCnt+=1
         print("Getting user %s of %s"%(userCnt,len(users)))
         count=1
        nCursor=-1#First page
        while count>0:
            id_str=user

            try:
               fh=open("user_output/"+str(id_str)+"_" + str(count) + ".json","r")
               result=fh.read()
               fh.close()
               wait=0
            except: 
               result=api.followers_ids(count=5000,user_id=id_str,cursor=nCursor)
               fh=open("user_output/"+str(id_str)+"_" + str(count) + ".json","w")
               fh.write(result)
               fh.close()
               wait=60


            result=json.loads(result)
            nCursor=result["next_cursor_str"]
            if nCursor=="0":
                count=-1
                nCursor=None
            else:
                count+=1
                print("Another page to get")

            time.sleep(wait)



    logPrint("\nDONE! Completed Successfully")
    fhLog.close()
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: for one thing, you never seem to assign the `result` variable in the first place. The first time it's used in your code is `result = json.loads(result)`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply.  I realised I accidentally omitted the code that defined `result`its the try/except loop after `id_str=user`.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not answer your question, but there are indentation problems in your imports...
Try this :

```
try:
  import json
except ImportError:
  import simplejson as json
import urllib2
import urllib
import codecs
import time
import datetime
import os
import random
import time
import tweepy
from tweepy.parsers import RawParser
import sys
```

Also, you can create a directory with os module directly. Try this:

```
if not os.path.exists("./user_output"):
  os.path.makedirs("./user_output")
```

Finally, you do a time.sleep(wait) but wait might not be set. Try this:

```
if  api.followers_ids(count=5000,user_id=id_str,cursor=nCursor):
  time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I fixed the things you pointed out, but it still doesn't work properly unfortunately. One thing I forgot to mention in the original post is that every time I run the program I get a different common follower id...every user has the same follower id, but the follower id that's repeated is different every time I run the program. I don't know if that is helpful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for tweepy indicates that the only parameter that api.followers_ids accepts is the id, user_id or screen_name, not the three arguments you are passing.

http://pythonhosted.org/tweepy/html/api.html#api-reference

You also need to assign the returned values to the result variable. Get rid of the if statement and put this in its place.

```
result=api.followers_ids(id_str)
wait=60
```